# How to delete a folder and its content from SDcard on Android 10 and Android 11

Tags: android, directory, android-10.0, android-11, scoped-storage

I have an application running on android and I'm saving some files that the app needs to download in the sdcard, only if the user wants to use the external storage instead to use the internal storage, so according to the update for OS 10 and OS 11 we need to migrate all that content to the scoped storage to be used only for my app, the process to copy the folder and its content from ex /storage/EREKD34/MyFolder to /storage/EREKD34/Android/data//MyFolder works, but to avoid to have duplicated files I need to delete the folder "MyFolder" but the function to delete that File doesn't work, so do you have any another idea how to do this

Comment: On an Android 10 device use SAF. On Android 11 device you can use SAF too or request all files access.

Comment: But i wonder.. how did the files land in that folder to begin with? As a removable micro sd card is read only since Kitkat. Well except if you use SAF.

Comment: Once the files are there on the micro sd card i see no reason to move them to that Android directory. Why would you?

Comment: The files were copied manually, instead to download the files and use the network in some case is better to copy manually the data, so according to scoped storage from Android, I need to move this folder into the scoped storage

Comment: Sorry but is still see no reason why you would need to move them. Certainly not when you have access. Further it is unclear what you do if you are manually copying data.

Comment: The idea is we are automatically copying the files into the scoped storage, it's a requirement but for now I'm asking to the user delete the folder manually it means that the user will have information duplicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s",getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_STORAGE_PERMISSION);
```

To give the permission to delete the folder with

DocumentFile document = getDocumentFile(file, false, true);
document.delete();

Comment: Wont this get your app rejected